# how to define regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex, migration, migrate

I need to replace a all string in source code document using regex like this:
`strcpy(x,"string is string")` become `_tcscpy(x,_T("string is string"));`.
actually , i need surround all string in function with T_ marco
How to define a regular expression pattern in c# to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do that, you could simply run a Replace from Edit menu using `strcpy(x,"string is string")` to be replaced and `_tcscpy(x,_T("string is string"));` as substitution, setting "Whole project".

Comment: actually , i need surround my string "string is string" with T_ marco.

Answer (score 1):

First, you import API of regular expression in your class for use it:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Second in your method, instantiate new Regex:

```
Regex regexName = new Regex(@"string of regexExpression", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Third, you analize your string or for extract your prefered part of string:

```
MatchCollection nameOfResult = regexName.Matches(this.yourString);
foreach (Match result in nomeOfResult)
        {
            System.out.println(result.ToString());
        }
```

Third-one, if you replace part of string corresponding your regex:

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, regexName);
```

Try by this pattern : strcpy.*x,.*string.*is.*string.*
For pattern or for test pattern use this: http://rubular.com/ or this: http://myregexp.com/